# Easyway to test two way network connectivity

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

I have a situation where I'd need to check network connectivity from client A to 40 hosts and vice versa. As logging on to each client takes time. I was wondering is there an easy way to achieve this, Please show some light.

Ex:

Destination 1:

Source to destination: OK

Destination to Source: KO

Source:

10.1.2.3

Destination:

10.2.2.2
10.3.3.3
10.4.4.4
10.5.5.5

Port: 8080

Can anyone help which module should I be using? Please.

Comment: Try to `ping` or `telnet` the clients?

Comment: nmap is also useful when specifying multiple addresses

Comment: @Avihoo Mamka.. telnet..

Comment: @RamanSailopal,  nmap is not available unfortunately..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work but I did not test it. Let me know if it helps you.

EDIT : Im editing since I realize you needed a "viceversa" way too. so here it is, assuming you have ssh keys between your main server and the 40 hosts you are trying to test. And as noted on the comments  this will work in Bash.

```
 #!/bin/bash

port=8080
viceversaIp="10.1.2.3"
while read line
do

    result=$( echo > /dev/tcp/$line/$port )
    if [ -z "$result" ]
    then
        echo "Server : $line ; Port : $port ;  The port is closed!!"
    else
        echo "Server : $line ; Port : $port ;  The port is open!!"
    fi
    result=""

    viceversa_result=$( ssh -n $line " echo > /dev/tcp/$viceversaIp/$port " | tail -1 )

    if [ -z "$viceversa_result" ]
    then
        echo "Server $line can reach $viceversaIp at port $port "
    else
        echo "Server $line can NOT reach $viceversaIp at port $port "
    fi
    viceversa_result=""

done <( cat ips.txt )
```

Regards!

Comment: This will only work if the user is using bash environment , however the op also tagged `ksh` and over korn shell this script would not work. Nice solution anyway, I didn't know you could use socket this way

Comment: @Will Yes, you are right, it will work only in Bash. Thanks for the encouragement also. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a oneliner using [netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) `nc`:

```
cat hosts.txt| xargs -n 1 sh -c 'nc -G1 -w1 -z $1 8080' argv0
```

In where the file `hosts.txt` contains an IP/domain per line.

if you have custom port per IP you could follow this format:

```
# IP PORT
10.10.0.1 8080
10.10.0.2 80
```

And do:

```
cat hosts.txt| xargs -n 2 sh -c 'nc -G1 -w1 -z $1 $2' argv0
```

**netcat** is connecting via TPC which connection is bidirectional (three-way handshake) so maybe satisfy your requirement of testing in "two way"

The option `-G` and `-w` are for timeouts:

```
-G conntimeout TCP connection timeout in seconds
-w If a connection and stdin are idle for more than timeout sec-
   onds, then the connection is silently closed.
```